# What is the replacement of Placeholder in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am new to Tensorflow and I have used tensorflow.placeholder() in tensorflow 1.0. But is there any replacement of placeholder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loosely speaking, the syntax element in TF 2 that most closely resembles a placeholder is the argument of a a function decorated with `@tf.function`. So whereas in TF 1 you had something like this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(...)
y = 2 * x
```

In TF 2 you write:

```
@tf.function
def my_function(x):
  y = 2 * x
  return y
```

Similarly, in TF 1 you had sessions:

```
y_val = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: tf.constant(1)})
```

But in TF 2 you have just function calls (with a few caveats about the type of their arguments - you have to explicitly make them Tensors):

```
y_val = my_function(tf.constant(1))
```

As you can see TF 2 changes the mental model a little bit, but hopefully the code you end up writing is more intuitive.

You can read more about it in [this RFC](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180918-functions-not-sessions-20.md).

Answer (score 4):

There is no replacement for placeholder in Tf2 as its default mode is eager execution , if want to use placeholder in tf2 than use tf.compat.v1 syntax and disable v2 behavior